# dropzonejs file types

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I'm using [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for a simple file-upload. I currently have a few issues though.

I don't know how to restrict the **types of files being uploaded**. I have file-verification on my PHP-backend, but files seem uploaded (they get a checkmark) even though they don't pass these filters. This isn't a real issue though. The only type of extra javascript-filtering I would like is the file type. Currently you can select any type of file, but I'd like to restrict this to image files in one uploader and pdf/word/excell in another. Can this be done in the plugin itself, or how can it be done with js elsewhere?

The plugin does not require jquery, but I'm using jquery elsewhere so it can be used for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dropzone documentation (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) there is the accept option -

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

All you have to do is modify it for your purposes, like accepting files with certain extensions.

Comment: Oh I'd seen that piece of code but didn't really think it through. I can use file.type to get the filetype. The issue is however, that it runs that code when a file is selected. the done() also does the same thing as after all my succesful uploads. So say you choose 20 correct files and then a wrong file, it does the done() function. In my case, the done() function does a window.location.reload();... Heres the full code: http://pastebin.com/AHxC9NWy

Comment: After some fumbling around I managed to fix it. Apparantly `done("error")` triggered the `complete` event. So in the complete event, I had a new if-statement. Since I don't want files to be auto-uploaded but only after a button is clicked, I checked to see if the button had been clicked. Here's the final code: http://pastebin.com/yUbkRqTA

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Dropzone default way of handling an error is to show it on the screen (as an X in its default template). In order to handle it differently, I handled the error event:

```
this.on('error', function (file, errorMessage, xhrError) {
        this.removeFile(file);
        alert(errorMessage);
    });
```

This way, an error is displayed, and no file uploaded UI illusion is displayed.

Comment: this in my opinion is a far better way from a UI perspective of dealing with files that are not allowed.